# Changed Geo Target of my blog on Google Search Console, How Long Will It Take To See Results?

Tags: geotargeting

Changed the geo targeting of my blog from unlisted to my country about a month ago but till now I have not seen any result, I have not seen any effect of the change. How long will it take to see the effects of the change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There won't be any change or effect. Usually Googlebot will figure out which country your are targeting. The change in Search Console only provides a **hint** to it, in order to identify that country or region better.